# Redirect back to previous url or to auth-protected url

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, redirect

**In e-commerce shop, the homepage have a lot of products, and every product has a link containing its own id (`/order/x`). When I click on that link, I force a login action with authentication middleware. When user clicks "buy this product" I want to redirect him to `/order/x` after successful login. But also, if the user clicks login from the homepage navigation, I want to redirect him back to the homepage.**

The case:
When I try to access a route, protected by authentication middleware (in this example: `/order/1`), my url.intended is stored as `/order/1`, and that's what I want. But when I press login from the homepage that points to `{{ route('login') }}`), the url.intended stays at the same - `/order/1` URL, unless I try to enter another auth-protected URL. I tried to use the previous URL method, but then it's not redirecting back to auth-protected routes URLs.
In this case (when using url.previous) -  If I press the "Buy product" button from the homepage, instead of returning to the order screen, it will redirect me back to the homepage.

**What's the best and working way to redirect the user to the previous URL if it clicks  on login from the homepage, or /order/1 URL if it clicks on "Buy product."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `redirect_url` query parameter while redirecting to the login page. And let the login controller redirect to the URL defined in the `redirect_url` parameter after the successful logging in.

Answer (score 3):

Use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in php It returns the complete URL of the page

Comment: When I use this on the homepage (by clicking the login button), it works fine, but when I press on the "Buy product" button, which is secured by auth middleware, it returns the same homepage URL.

Comment: Display products link as per the  condition:
If user is logged in - product_url
If user is not logged in - pass product id as parameter in login url. On login page after successfull login check product id exist in url or not. If product id found redirect on product page else redirect on Home Page